# Grafana converts substracted year to 1753, other tools to 0001 (expected)

Tags: postgresql

I'm running the following query with three different tools: pgAdmin, TablePlus and Grafana

```
select timestamp '2023-12-25' -interval '2022 years' as date
```

Both TablePlus and pgAdmin give me the following result:

```
0001-12-25 00:00:00
```

But Grafana gives me something that does not makes sense to me:

```
1755-08-23 23:01:11
```

The result from TablePlus/pgAdmin is what I expect the date to be.
With this query I'm not actually retrieving any data from a database, but to cancel out any version related issues, I'm connecting to the same dbms (and database) to run this statement.

Does Grafana do some under-the-hood conversion that I'm not aware of? And how to avoid it?

Version: PostgreSQL 10.10 (Debian 10.10-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit